# Two DIVs Side by Side Giving Extra Space at the bottom...

Tags: html, css

I need to place 2 fixed width DIVs side by side inside another big fixed width DIV and it is working. This is the code that I have written :

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="divLeft">      <img src="bla bla bla" >     </div>
    <div id="divRight">   Normal Text Here.....  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#mainDiv { width:1100;overflow:hidden; }

#divLeft { width:720; float:left;}

#divRight { width:380; float:right;}
```

The problem is, when I placed the image of size 720X480 into the first DIV, the height of the first DIV ("divLeft") is becoming 485. Why its giving an extra 
5px ?

You can view the page here : http://www.touchmedia.ca/TestPos.php

Please Note the following:
I did overflow:hidden for the main div, b'cos, otherwise, the float will remove the effect of outer div.
I have hardcoded only the width and not the height.
main div width (1100) = left div width (720) + right div width (380)

Thanks a lot,

Isaac

Comment: try adding `margin:0px` and `padding:0px`
and of course add
`<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the mainDiv to prevent any hazzle there

Comment: Geoffrey Burdett or Reconstruct's methods will work. Tested.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
#divLeft img {
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your style sheet:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```